# How to get form html() via jQuery including updated value attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Is it possible to get the html of a form with updated value attributes via the .html() function?

The (simplified) HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="some_radio" value="1" checked="checked">
    <input type="radio" name="some_radio" value="2"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="some_input" value="Default Value">
</form><br>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        alert($('form').html());
    });
});
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/brLgC/2/

After changing the value of the input and pressing "click me" it still returns the HTML with the default values.

How can I simply get the updated HTML via jQuery?

Comment: I don't believe so, since the values are never set with JS, they are just returned as what they are hard-coded as. You can always use `.serialize()`

Comment: because you are alerting the actual HTML ... what you type doesn't get added to the HTML building the page. likely ull need to do a loop through each item, get the html and value, and combine it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really must have the HTML, you need to actually update the "value" attribute manually:
http://jsfiddle.net/brLgC/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        $("input,select,textarea").each(function() {
           if($(this).is("[type='checkbox']") || $(this).is("[type='checkbox']")) {
             $(this).attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
           }
           else {
              $(this).attr("value", $(this).val()); 
           }
        });
        alert($('form').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess that's the only solution then... however I guess it's a bit trickier with radio buttons and checkboxes...

Comment: Updated solution for radios & checkboxes. Same principal, except using the checked attribute rather than value. Sure, it's messy, but calling .html() normally is.

Comment: as @tymeJV mentioned above, `serialize()` will also work, making this a little bit cleaner.

Comment: .serialize() only provides key/value pairs as a string. He wants the literal HTML from the web page.

Comment: I have added your script to a change listener for all my form fields

Answer (score 5):

RGraham's answer wasn't working for me so I modified it to:

```
$("input, select, textarea").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is("[type='radio']") || $this.is("[type='checkbox']")) {
        if ($this.prop("checked")) {
            $this.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    } else {
        if ($this.is("select")) {
            $this.find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
        } else {
            $this.attr("value", $this.val());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Lachlan's works "almost" perfect. The issue is when the form is saved and then restored then saved again the radio and checkboxs do not uncheck and instead just keep compounding. Simple fix below.

```
$("input, select, textarea").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is("[type='radio']") || $this.is("[type='checkbox']")) {
        if ($this.prop("checked")) {
            $this.attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $this.removeAttr("checked");
        }
    } else {
        if ($this.is("select")) {
            $this.find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
        } else {
            $this.attr("value", $this.val());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working with textarea

Answer (score 1):

The working version along with textarea is below

```
$("input, select, textarea").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is("[type='radio']") || $this.is("[type='checkbox']")) {
        if ($this.prop("checked")) {
            $this.attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $this.removeAttr("checked");
        }
    } else {
        if ($this.is("select")) {
            $this.find(":selected").attr("selected", "selected");
        } else if ($this.is("textarea")) {
                $this.html($this.val());
        } else {
            $this.attr("value", $this.val());
        }
    }
});
```