# Html of template haven't got values

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to get html of my input with some value (`{{title}}` is some `String`, it displays in my template, but not in `console.log`)

```
<div class="www">
    <input name="title" id="post_edit_title" value="{{title}}"/>
</div>

    $(t.find(".www")).html()
```

and it outputs  `<input name="title" id="post_edit_title"/>`

How to get correct `html` ?

Comment: If you need to get the html with the input values you need to update the `value` attribute manually. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16818509/151689) there is a solution to this.

Comment: What do you think your expected output should be?

Comment: @andy `<input name="title" id="post_edit_title" value="somestring"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a couple of ways...

If `www` is one of elements with that class, use [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to grab the one you need:

```
$('.www').eq(0).html();
```

Or target the input by its `id` and grab the HTML of its parent.

```
$('#post_edit_title').parent().html();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9gjhz982/)

Comment: all ok, I solved it, and yourr solution ony for 1 element in `.www`