# clear dom cache of jquery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an jQuery element $foo

it contain html with a textarea. But if I change the value of textarea and use $foo.html() after this change, the html result is not actualized...

(bad) exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/sNYYD/781/

```
var $foo = $('#foo'); console.log($foo.html());

$foo.on('keyup', function(){console.log($foo.html());});
```

how remove or disabled jquery dom cache?

EDIT EXEMPLE ======================================================

I do a simple exemple, but the answer go on bad way, sry about that, my use case is more specefic and looks like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/sNYYD/790/

I need know how found good key to delete in `$.cache` for my element, to actualise html of element in my global var.

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Your issue is because you're reading the HTML of the parent element. This does not change when the `value` property of an input is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the text in the text-area doesn't affect the actual html, that is why you are always getting the same value. If you need only the text you can use one of the other solutions if however you need the whole html you have to take the value and put it into the actual html like this:

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
console.log($foo.html());

$foo.on('keyup', function()
{
    $("#textArea").html($("#textArea").val());
    console.log($foo.html());
});
```

**UPDATE**
This is the solution for your new example.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sNYYD/792/

Comment: Look at the updated js fiddle for the solution with your new example

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the actual textarea's value:

```js
    var $foo = $('#foo');
    console.log($foo.html());

    $foo.on('keyup', function(){console.log($foo.find('textarea').val());});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
    <textarea>testing 123</textarea>
</div>
```

See the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sNYYD/782/

Answer (score 0):

Because `textarea` only display data via `val()` not ah `html()` . You are calling the only HTML But Textarea does not support to display the typed `text content` via `html()`  function call

```js
var $foo = $('#foo');
console.log($foo.html());
$foo.on('keyup', function() {
  console.log($foo.html());
  console.log($foo.find('textarea').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- By http://jquery4u.com / Sam Deering -->
<div id="foo">
  <textarea>test</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate answers i would say [How to get form html() via jQuery including updated value attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818395/how-to-get-form-html-via-jquery-including-updated-value-attributes)

and removing or disabling DOM cache using jQuery is not possible i feel.

Comment: the cache are here : $.cache so it's not impossible to remove it for one element... I just don't know how to get good cache for my specific element

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
$(this).html(console.log($(this).val()))
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
    <textarea>testing 123</textarea>
</div>
```