# How to get updated html() when there are changes to css classes or div text contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with html() function of JQuery, which doesn't return updated css of the divs.

My divs are encapsulated in parent div. In JQuery, according to some logic, I add or remove css classes on divs through addClass() or removeClass().
I also change text content of some divs.

Later I want to use html() function to get whole html of updated parent html() and copy somewhere else.

html() function() get initial html and doesn't get ant changes :(

I founded this topic, but there is described solution to update values of form:
[similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818395/how-to-get-form-html-via-jquery-including-updated-value-attributes)

Is there any similar solution to update css classes and div text contents, so html() function will pick up changes to them?

Comment: I test it with jQuery 3.2.1, the html() works fine, can you provide you demo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that because you save the `html()` to var, then you call the var instead using the new one. see the example

```js
$(function(){
  var first = $('p').html();
  console.log(first); //first
  $('p').html('second');
  console.log(first); //first
  console.log($('p').html()); //second
  $('p').html('third');
  console.log(first); //first
  console.log($('p').html()); //third
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>first</p>
```